# Number of non-commutative Lie algebras of dimension 2

Tags: lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Theorem- Up to isomorphism, the only noncommutative Lie algebra of dimension 2 is that with
basis $x , y$ and bracket determined by $[x,y] = x$.

I understand that all vector spaces of dimension 2 over the field $K$ are isomorphic to each other. So the number of lie algebras of dimension 2 in a field $K$ is determined by the number of possible bilinear operations [ ]$:\ V \ X \ V  \rightarrow V$ satisfying the conditions

$a)$ $[x,x]=0$ for all $x\in V$

$b)$ $[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]]+[z,[x,y]]=0$ for all $x,y,z \in V$

The bilinear operations on the other hand is determined by the elements to which the pair of base elements are mapped to in the bilinear operation. And since in a lie algebra $[x,x]=[y,y]=0$ and $[x,y]=-[x,y]$ we ony need to determine $[x,y]$. Now how do we prove that $[x,y]=x$ and $[y,x]=-x$ always and why can't it be [y,x]=y or any other vector ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classsifying 1- and 2- dimensional Algebras, up to Isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24601/classsifying-1-and-2-dimensional-algebras-up-to-isomorphism)

Comment: It's certainly not necessarily true that $[x,y]=x$, since you only know that the Lie bracket has this form *up to some isomorphism*.  That is, you can *find* a basis $\{x,y\}$ such that $[x,y]=x$, but it probably won't be true if you just start with some random basis.

Comment: Besides the link given by @LukasMiaskiwskyi, many answers to any of its more-or-less-duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2330090/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222743/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135076/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1384110/96384 contain insights. Also, fully agreed with what EricWofsey says.